# Remove white space in xsl

Tags: xslt, whitespace

How can I get rid of the space that gets added after the "Location" element which is breaking the links? IE: "/location toxxx.aspx"
XML

```
- <Root>
 <Schema>
 <Field Type="Text" DisplayName="Location" Required="FALSE" MaxLength="255"  Name="Location" /> 
 <Field Type="Currency" DisplayName="Price one way-saloon" Required="FALSE" Decimals="0" LCID="2057" Name="Price_x0020_one_x0020_way" /> 
 <Field Type="Currency" DisplayName="Price return-saloon" Required="FALSE" Decimals="0" LCID="2057" Name="Price_x0020_return" /> 
 <Field ReadOnly="TRUE" Type="Computed" Name="LinkTitle" DisplayName="Location id" /> 
 <Field Type="Currency" DisplayName="Price one way-estate" Required="FALSE" Decimals="0" LCID="2057" Name="Price_x0020_one_x0020_way_x002d_" /> 
 <Field Type="Currency" DisplayName="Price return-estate" Required="FALSE" Decimals="0" LCID="2057" Name="Price_x0020_return_x002d_estate" /> 
 <Field Type="Currency" DisplayName="Price one way-MPV" Required="FALSE" Decimals="0" LCID="2057" Name="Price_x0020_one_x0020_way_x002d_0" /> 
 <Field Type="Currency" DisplayName="Price return-MPV" Required="FALSE" Decimals="0" LCID="2057" Name="Price_x0020_return_x002d_MPV" /> 
 <Field Type="Currency" DisplayName="Price one way-MPV+" Required="FALSE" Decimals="0" LCID="2057" Name="Price_x0020_one_x0020_way_x002d_1" /> 
 <Field Type="Currency" DisplayName="Price return-MPV+" Required="FALSE" Decimals="0" LCID="2057" Name="Price_x0020_return_x002d_MPV_x00" /> 
 </Schema>
 <Data ItemCount="1">
 <Row Location="" Price_x0020_one_x0020_way="" Price_x0020_return="" LinkTitle="" Price_x0020_one_x0020_way_x002d_="" Price_x0020_return_x002d_estate="" Price_x0020_one_x0020_way_x002d_0="" Price_x0020_return_x002d_MPV="" Price_x0020_one_x0020_way_x002d_1="" Price_x0020_return_x002d_MPV_x00="" /> 
</Data>
</Root>
```

XSL

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="html" /> 
      <xsl:template match="/">
 <div id="locations">
 <ul id ="navbar" class="MSC_PrimaryNavFrame">
 <li><a href="#"><b>Going to Heathrow?<br />Find your fare fast!</b></a>
 <ul class="locations">
 <xsl:for-each select="//Data/Row">
 <li><a><xsl:attribute name ="href"><xsl:value-of  select="@Location"/>_toheathrow.aspx</xsl:attribute>
 <xsl:value-of select = "@Location" />
 </a>
 </li>
 </xsl:for-each>
 </ul>
 </li>
 </ul>
 </div></xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Sorry if I didn't post the code correctly-if I leave in line breaks it removes parts.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for three different XSLT 1.0 solutions and a fourth one that is available only in XSLT 2.0. I recommend using AVTs always when this is possible.

Comment: Bad question -1! The code you've posted won't add the whitespace you're complaining about. I get the impression your real code was different and had whitespace adjacent to the "toHeathrow" string - but you've left me guessing.

Comment: @Michael Kay: I think that @matt had difficulties formatting his code. When I read the question there was a carriage return and white-space following "toHeathrow.aspx" -- could be result of my own IDE's  re-formatting.

Comment: @Dimitre, Thanks for the suggestions. I hope I fixed the code posting problems. I was able to workaround this simply by adding an underscore where the space was appearing. but I'm going to try out the AVT idea now as I'd rather lose the underscore.

Comment: @Michael, Sorry about the formatting problem. There was no visible white space but it was there when the links were clicked. The underscore I added elininated the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**There are at least three different ways of doing this**:

1. **Using AVT ([Attribute-Value Templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates)) -- recommended**

   ```
       <li>
           <a href="{@Location}toheathrow.aspx">
               <xsl:value-of select = "@Location" />
           </a>
       </li>
   ```
2. **Using the standard XPath function `concat()`**:

--

```
<a>
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
     <xsl:value-of select=
     "concat(@Location,'toheathrow.aspx')"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select = "@Location" />
</a>
```

.3. **Using the Xslt instruction `<xsl:text>`:**

--

```
<a>
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
     <xsl:value-of select="@Location"/>

     <xsl:text>toheathrow.aspx</xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select = "@Location" />
</a>
```

.4. **Also, in XSLT 2.0 one can use a `select` attribute on the `<xsl:attribute>` instruction**:

```
<li>
    <a>
        <xsl:attribute name="href"
         select="concat(@Location, 'toheathrow.aspx')"/>
        <xsl:value-of select = "@Location" />
    </a>
</li>
```

**I recommend using AVTs always when this is possible** -- thus making the code shorter, simpler and more understandable.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Please do not post XML documents in one line. Provided XML (fragment, because there is no root) does not match to XSL stylesheet (`Field` empty elements with some attributes, but definitely no `Location` attribute here and `//Data/Row` path).</strike>

You provided just part of XSL with `xsl:for-each` loop. I guess that you are looking for something like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//Data/Row">
    <li>
        <a href="{@Location}toheathrow.aspx">
            <xsl:value-of select="@Location"/>
        </a>
    </li>
</xsl:for-each>
```

If `@Location` attribute's value has spaces in itself, then you can additionally use [`normalize-space()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space) function (from XPath 1.0). For example:

```
normalize-space('  some scattered    value   ') = 'some scattered value'
```

**EDIT:**

Changed `{concat(@Location, 'toheathrow.aspx')}` to `{@Location}toheathrow.aspx`. It's rightly more compact.